# field of fractions of finite ring extension

Tags: vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, extension-field

> I have a finite extension of domains $A\hookrightarrow B$ which induce a finite field extension $k:=\operatorname{Frac}(A)\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Frac}(B)=:K$. How can I prove $K=B\otimes_Ak$ (isomorphism as vector spaces over $k$).

Clearly I have that the right-hand-module is contained in the left, but why is there an equality?

Thank you!!

Comment: The right hand side is a finite ring extension of a field, hence a field itself.

Comment: oh. I see.... That was easy. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: In other words you want to prove that $K=S^{-1}B$, where $S=A\setminus\{0\}$. But $S^{-1}A=k\subset S^{-1}B$ is still finite, so $S^{-1}B$ is a field which contains $B$ and is contained in $K$, hence the conclusion.